# Prevent next keydown event until script execution finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable the keydown event to happen, until the script inside the keydown event finish execution.

```
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 40){
           down(); //Assume down has some animate function executes for 1sec
        }
   });
```

Currently, when I press down key and keep it without releasing, keydown event fires repeatedly, I want to disable that.

Comment: Have you tried returning it as false; afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution based on Asad's answer:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if( $('body').hasClass('animating')){
        //DO NOTHING
    }
    else{
        if (e.keyCode == 40){
           down(); //Assume down has some animate function executes for 1sec
           $('body').addClass('animating');
        }
    }
 });


$(document).keyup(function(e){
    $('body').removeClass('animating');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could unbind the event once the keydown event occurs:

```
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 40){
           down(); //Assume down has some animate function executes for 1sec
           $(document).unbind('keydown');
        }
   });
```

then rebind in the `down` function once the animation has completed (as a callback, probably).

If you're not interested in binding/rebinding, and don't like icky global variables, you could use a class to indicate whether an animation is in progress:

```
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 40 && $('body').is(':not(.animating)')){
           down(); //Assume down has some animate function executes for 1sec
           $('body').addClass('animating');
        }
   });
```

then remove it in the `down` function once the animation has completed, in much the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Keep some variable and check it also

```
var isAnimating = false;
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (!isAnimating && e.keyCode == 40){
        isAnimating = true;
        down(); //Assume down has some animate function executes for 1sec
        isAnimating = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Binding and rebinding is expensive. Just keep track of whether animation is in progress with a variable, and check before doing it again:

```
var animating = false;

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 40 && !animating){
       down(); //Assume down has some animate function executes for 1sec
       animating = true;
    }
```

});

Then you can use a settimeout with an appropriate delay to set animating back to false;

Comment: I'm not sure that was worth a downvote, it makes absolutely no difference as the animation is clearly asycnhronous.

Answer (score -1):

You can't prevent the event from firing, but you can just ignore it:

```
var keyIsDown = false;
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(!keyIsDown) {
        keyIsDown = true;
        if (e.keyCode == 40){
            down(); //Assume down has some animate function executes for 1sec
            // set keyIsDown = false; on the animation callback, inside down func.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That does nothing. 'keyIsDown' must be unset in the down-function.

Comment: @Nirazul Actually, I just realized it should be unset on the callback to `.animate`. Updated.